# How to get a List of blend file Scenes without bpy module

Tags: python, game-engine, scene

I'm creating a game, and my intention is to create a code that can run in the Standalone-Player, since I want a way to distribute it to him. Aafter creating my codes all related to the BPY module, I realized that when running in the "Standalone-Player" the code doesn't work, due to the lack of BPY support at runtime. A research showed me that it's very unlikely to use it in a "trivial" way with the "Standalone-Player".

My problem arises with the listing of some "resources" of the file itself, and I can't find a way to access it through the BGE module.

**e.g. A way to list all scenes in the file that are not yet activated:**

**(since `bge.logic.getSceneList()` only returns scenes that are already active)**

```
        # CONFIG VIDEO
        # call its asigned before as a scene actuator 
        # c = python controller

    if str(mo.hitObject) == 'Config_BT3':
        # OPEN OVERLAY CONFIG -> VIDEO
        VID = bpy.data.scenes['Main_MENU_VIDEO_CONFIG'] # <-- **HERE IS THE DEAL**
        #Assing Scene to Load and Call him
        call.scene = VID.name 
        c.activate(call)
```

Comment: UPBGE +0.3 can run BPY realtime, entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bge.types.KX_Scene` objects are created on runtime and represent active scenes. Inactive scenes aren't loaded into memory beforehand and therefore aren't available to the BGE until loaded in using the `Scene` actuator or `bge.logic.AddScene()`. The code in these that loads scenes is implemented within the BGE source and is not accessible via the Python API. You will just have to maintain a list of valid scene names and manage them manually.

If you really need a list of the resources, you could have the data stored by the BPY API before you export out your application. You can make a short script that maintains a .txt or .json that represents the static data you want to have about your game.

Another possible option is switching to UPBGE, which IIRC allows for use of bpy data.